# Entity Framework, Code First, Update independent association (Collection)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, ef-code-first

to explain the problem I have a simple model with a class Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a class School with a collection of Persons:

```
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Pupils { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a School works fine:

```
using (DatabaseContext ctx = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            Person p = new Person() { Name = "Thomas" };
            Person p2 = new Person() { Name = "Markus" };
            School s = new School();
            s.Name = "Test";
            s.Pupils = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            s.Pupils.Add(p);
            s.Pupils.Add(p2);
            ctx.Schools.Add(s);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

and in the persons table the school_id foreign key is set correctly:

```
Id     Name    School_Id

1      Thomas     1 
2      Markus     1
```

But when I try to add a new Pupil:

```
using (DatabaseContext ctx = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            Person p = new Person() { Name = "Mark" };
            s.Pupils.Add(p);
            ctx.Persons.Add(p);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

the School_id is set to null in the database table:

```
 Id     Name    School_Id

 1      Thomas     1 
 2      Markus     1  
 3      Mark      null
```

What am I doing wrong? I know that I could use the Foreign Key Association but as I plan to use the Person Entity with different related entities I prefer the independent association.

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: sounds like `s` is not attached to the context you should have `s = ctx.Set<School>().Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();`.

Comment: tschmitt007 thank you very much. This was the problem. Now it works. If you write this as an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like s is not attached to the dbcontext you should have

```
s = ctx.Set<School>().Where(x => x.Id == 1).First();
```

Please notice that 1 is a hardcoded value, you should have a variable valued according to the application context.

Please also notice that if the suggestion of Jan is not the solution to your specific problem, his advice is good and should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse your Pupils collection is null when you create your poco (even thru `Set.Add(Set.Create())`, rewrite your School poco as:

```
private HashSet<Person> _pupils

public ICollection<Person> Pupils { 
  get {return _pupils ?? (_pupils = new HashSet<Person>());}
  set{_pupils = value;} 
}
```

**Edit:** I notice just now you have `s.Pupils.Add(p);` (but i dont see where you get `s`) - are you really using it this way? It should throw null exception... Or by any chances, is your proxy creating disabled? (it should be enabled ;) )

**Edit2:** `s.Pupils = new ObservableCollection<Person>();` -- you practically throw away EF generated proxy collection, so any .Add() is not tracked and changes are not pushed to FK property (your `p.School` is `null`)

Comment: if the Pupils was nul, it would throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: yeah, i overlooked that... But if you can, please try it - this solve many problems with EF (maybe it is overriden later)

Comment: This did not help. Foreign Key is still set to null

Comment: and throw away `s.Pupils = new ObservableCollection<Person>();` -- you really want EF collections (they are proxies!) ---- i think this is it, you dont use proxy-ef-created collection but your ObservableCollection, so FK is not updated correctly (Mark dont have any School object before SaveChanges() )